# Javascript to create new <div> dynamically and fill it with the existing DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

I'm learning javascript and playing around with adding/removing elements in the DOM, but I'm confused about something that seems like it should be simple. I want to create a new div wrapper with ID around all the elements in the body. I'd prefer to do this with Vanilla Javascript and not jQuery if possible.

HTML:

```
<h1>Javascript Testing Header</h1>
<p>This is some text inside of my javascript testing page.</p>
<p>This is another simple paragraph.</p>
<h2>I like foods like:</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Chocolate</li>
    <li>Thin Mints</li>
    <li>Tiger Trees</li>
    <li>Feet Mangroves</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
// puts all the elements in <body> into it's own variable
var header1 = document.querySelector('h1');
var para = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var header2 = document.querySelector('h2');
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

// creates the new dynamic div 
var newDivWrapper = document.createElement('div');
// gives newly created dynamic div id=container
newDivWrapper.id = 'container';

var bodyTag = document.querySelector('body');

// appends the newDivWrapper to the end of the DOM, just above </body>
var newDivWrapper = bodyTag.appendChild(newDivWrapper);

function replaceContent() {
    document.newDivWrapper.innerHTML = header1 + para + header2 + list;
}
replaceContent();
```

The above does not work, it will create the new div and add it at the end of the DOM. But, I'm not sure if I should be deleting the old elements in the DOM after saving them to a var, or if their position can be moved. Also, I'm pretty sure that I can't use innerHTML to write anything other than text into an element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, with the exception of the `replaceContent()` method:

1. You have to use `newDivWrapper.appendChild(...)` instead of writing innerHTML, since `.innerHTML` expects a string, but `header`, `header2`, and `list` are HTML nodes and `para` is a NodeList.
2. For `para`, you will have to iterate through the node list to append each node individually to `newDivWrapper`
3. You do not need to reassign `newDivWrapper`. Instead simply move the line that appends it to the body after `replaceContent()` is called

With the comments above in mind, we can rewrite the last part of your code into this:

```
function replaceContent() {
    // #1: Use appendChild to append header1 to your new element
    newDivWrapper.appendChild(header1);

    // #2: para is a NodeList, so you have to loop through it
    [].slice.call(para).forEach(function(node) {
      newDivWrapper.appendChild(node);
    });

    // #1: Use appendChild to append header2 and list to your new element
    newDivWrapper.appendChild(header2);
    newDivWrapper.appendChild(list);
}
replaceContent();

// #3: Append your new element after everything is sorted out
bodyTag.appendChild(newDivWrapper);
```

---

Here is a proof-of concept example:

```js
// puts all the elements in <body> into it's own variable
var header1 = document.querySelector('h1');
var para = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var header2 = document.querySelector('h2');
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

// creates the new dynamic div 
var newDivWrapper = document.createElement('div');
// gives newly created dynamic div id=container
newDivWrapper.id = 'container';

var bodyTag = document.querySelector('body');

function replaceContent() {
    newDivWrapper.appendChild(header1);
    
    // para is a NodeList, so you have to loop through it
    [].slice.call(para).forEach(function(node) {
      newDivWrapper.appendChild(node);
    });
    
    newDivWrapper.appendChild(header2);
    newDivWrapper.appendChild(list);
}
replaceContent();

bodyTag.appendChild(newDivWrapper);
```

```html
<h1>Javascript Testing Header</h1>
<p>This is some text inside of my javascript testing page.</p>
<p>This is another simple paragraph.</p>
<h2>I like foods like:</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Chocolate</li>
    <li>Thin Mints</li>
    <li>Tiger Trees</li>
    <li>Feet Mangroves</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it works perfectly. Out of curiosity, I tried passing multiple HTML elements through the `[].slice.call(para).forEach(p) {}` by calling a .class instead of just all the p tags. I gave the same class to all the p tags and a single list item. It took the list item out of the ul and put it at the end of all the p tags. Since we passed the `forEach(p)`, why wouldn't it ignore the list item?

Comment: @Lavert the `forEach(function(p) {...})`, the `p` is not a selector but simply refers to the individual node in the nodelist. Think of it as a reference/pointer/accessor to the an array item in an array when iterating through it. Read the docs on how [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used :) I have updated my answer to rename the `p` variable to avoid confusion.